# MongoDB PredicateTranslator fails during OData ElemMatch $filter query

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, odata, iqueryable

I'm writing an OData v4 service. I'm using MongoDB for my back end.  I can easily write ElemMatch queries using `FilterDefinition<T>` to solve my problem:

```
var eqF = Builders<IndicesType>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Value, "Foo");
var elemF = Builders<DocumentType>.Filter.ElemMatch(_ => _.Indices, eqF);
```

I've tried returning an `IQueryable` and an `IMongoQueryable` from my repository using the `IMongoCollection#AsQueryable()` method.  The C# driver is throwing an InvalidOperationException when I try to use the following OData filter on my endpoint:

```
$filter=Indices/any(i: i/Value eq 'Foo')
```

The exception message is

`"IIF(({document}{i} == null), null, Convert(Any({document}{i}.Where((IIF(({document} == null), null, {document}{k}) == \"Foo\"))))) is not supported."`

I thought this operation would be supported by the new driver's extensive LINQ support.  Are there plans for this to be implemented or am I going to need to write a translation layer to convert OData queries into Mongo Filters or a BsonDocument and run the query manually?

For testing, casting the whole collection to an IEnumerable allows for proper filtering, but this solution obviously won't work for production when the collection size increases.

Are there any other workarounds I should consider?

**Edit**: found the JIRA ticket here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1771 which actually has a workaround if one were inclined to create a custom build of the driver.